# Function template specialization for function pointer

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, function-pointers

I just started to look into c++ templates when i came across [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). I really like the function declaration as a template argument so i came up with the following idea:

How would i implement a function which allows me to call it like this:

**(1)**

```
void(*pointer_to_function)(int, int) = get_pointer_to_function<void(int, int)>();
```

I took the definition of std::function as shown in the link above and gave it a shot. The result allowed me to write this and gave me insight on how to separate the return type and argument types from a function declaration:

**(2)**

```
template<typename>
struct function;

template<typename ReturnType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
struct function<ReturnType(ArgumentTypes...)> {};

function<void(int, int)> my_function;
```

I figured i could write this and use template argument deduction to fill in the types:

**(3)**

```
void(*get_pointer_to_function())(int, int) {
    return nullptr;
}
```

I came up with this:

**(4)**

```
template<typename FunctionType>
FunctionType* get_pointer_to_function();

template<typename ReturnType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
ReturnType(*get_pointer_to_function<ReturnType(ArgumentTypes...)>())(ArgumentTypes...) {
  return nullptr;
}
```

but the compiler yelled at me:

> ...main.cpp(70): error C2909: 'get_pointer_to_function': explicit instantiation of function template requires return type
>
> main.cpp(70): error C2768: 'get_pointer_to_function' : illegal use of explicit template arguments

I just recently started out with c++ and now with templates so i thought maybe i made a simple mistake in the declaration. I made it return void so the declaration is a bit easier.

**(5)**

```
template<typename>
void get_function_pointer();

template<typename ReturnType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
void get_function_pointer<ReturnType(ArgumentTypes...)>() {}
```

This time the compiler yelled at me only once and the first error disappeared.

> main.cpp(48): error C2768: 'get_function_pointer' : illegal use of
>   explicit template arguments

After a long while banging my head onto my keyboard, browsing the interwebz i came up with something that compiled and ran:

**(6)**

```
template<typename>
struct function_pointer;

template<typename ReturnType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
struct function_pointer<ReturnType(ArgumentTypes...)> {
  typedef ReturnType(*type)(ArgumentTypes...);
};

template<typename FunctionType>
typename function_pointer<FunctionType>::type get_function_pointer() {
  return nullptr;
}

int main() {
  auto pointer_to_function = get_function_pointer<void(int, int)>();

  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(pointer_to_function), void(*)(int, int)>::value, "Not the same");

  return 0;
}
```

However i think i this piece of code is way too complicated and i expect the piece of code at **(4)** to just work.

Did i do something wrong here? and why it it illegal?

Comment: You cannot partially specialize a template function, which is what you were trying to do in (4). The code in (6) solves this by moving it out to a template class, which can be partially specialized.